# Errno 5 while installing Ubuntu 12.04 via live USB

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, live-usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 using live USB but I am getting this error message:

> The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk: [Errno 5] Input/output error This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment.

Why am I facing this problem when I'm using a live USB, not a CD?DVD? How can I get past it? I want to install Ubuntu on my hard disk.

Comment: Related questions with the same error: [Hard disk error](https://askubuntu.com/q/30773/955434), ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/65830/955434), [Error when installing Ubuntu 20.04 on Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/q/1325340/955434), [Ubuntu 16.04 installation failed "did not match source copy"](https://askubuntu.com/q/1037057/955434), [Installation errno5 u ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1347872/955434), [Error when installing Ubuntu 20.04 in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/q/1239382/955434)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Such errors usually indicate that some files on the Live CD/USB are corrupted. Since you use a USB, the files may have been corrupted while downloading. If you don't have the .iso image, please download it, and then check its integrity.

You'll have to check you memory using a memtest. Also, check the .iso image using instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

You can download the image using the live USB. Boot from the USB stick and select "Try Ubuntu". Open Firefox and go to download the .iso, but make sure you download it to another USB stick or hard disk and not to any of the live CD's home folder directories, to ensure you don't run out of RAM and crash.

Alternatively, you could use the bittorrent downloads using [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BitTorrent) to make sure you don't get any data flaws.