# Installation errno5 u ubuntu 21.04

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive

The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:

[Errno 5] Input/output error

This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard
disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower
speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often
available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk
is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler
environment.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO before writing to media?  The error you've got relates to your installation media meaning you failed to verify the ISO, or the write to your media failed...  CD refers to installation media (be it CD/DVD/HDD/SSD/thumb-drive/CF/tape or any media your machine can boot & install from).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile)

Comment: In practice I find the write to installation media is the real problem; failure rate of 5-8% is what I expect...   I'd also suggest reading the second (no upvote) answer more than the accepted answer :)  or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311183/do-i-need-to-check-the-integrity-of-a-ubuntu-install

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu)