# Will “Erase Ubuntu16.10 and reinstall” keep my Win7 installation?

Tags: boot, 16.04, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I want to install a new Ubuntu on a drive where a previous Ubuntu system is already installed beside Windows7.

The first option says that only Ubuntu will be replaced.

The second says that all will be erased.

I only want Ubuntu replaced with the  new one while keeping Windows7 untouched.

Is the first option (“Erase Ubuntu16.10 and reinstall”) the good one in this case?

Comment: @karel - Do you know if that is really the answer? that is; is that bug still active in 16.04? should the first option be avoided and manual used instead?

Comment: A [fix for bug #1265192](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+milestone/ubuntu-14.04.2) was released for 14.04.

Comment: @karel - you should post that info as answer under the question that you linked here. Otherwise the standing answer is not a good answer for my question here; before that, it is not true that "This question may already have an answer here etc and therefore this is not a duplicate. That is 14.04 this is 16.04 question.

Comment: Best practice would be to [backup](http://askubuntu.com/a/586172/225694) for safety regardless. A [power failure](http://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing) or [hardware failure](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30773/hard-disk-error) can lead to unintended consequences even with tried and true solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Erase Ubuntu and reinstall* option in the **Installation type** screen of the Ubuntu installer will erase Ubuntu and reinstall it over the existing Ubuntu partitions without overwriting Windows if Windows is installed alongside Ubuntu.

[image]

This was reported as a critical bug in Ubuntu 13.10:
[Install/reinstall wipes out all/other partitions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192) and a [fix for this bug](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+milestone/ubuntu-14.04.2) was released in the Ubuntu 14.04.2 point release.

Comment: I have to test it myself to be sure, it's too risky and when a bug arrives it's too late.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I choose "Something else" part and format my main Ubuntu partition and install on that partition, never see an error after that.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't pose any problems, but just in case the best would be for you to backup your disc. In this blogpost there's a how to guide for [cloning your hard drive using the Ubuntu live cd](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19141/clone-a-hard-drive-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/). Whenever you are playing with partitions you have to be careful.