# Live usb install on old PC - disk error

Tags: live-usb, disk

I am trying to revive an old PC which used to run windows 7.

1. I created a bootable usb with an ubuntu image on it
2. I changed the boot sequence and some bios parameters (SpeedStart disabled / Legacy OS disabled)
3. I am able to boot on the key + start the ubuntu install sequence
4. During install, I get a disk error and the install never finishes
5. I created another live usb with disk recovery tools, such as gparted and Boot-info / boot-repair
6. GParted shows me 2 partitions /dev/sda1 - EFI System PArtition / 512Mo which is the boot partition and /dev/sda2 - which has an 'unknown' filesystem - 297.59GiB
7. The Boot-info file is here : http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Cjdy68FfTr/

=> I'm not sure what is the issue and how I can fix this to install ubuntu. I don't care about the potential existing data, no problem to format everything.

Any help is welcome !

Comment: Disk error during install could be a hardware fault. Look up how to run a SMART test on your disk.

Comment: You can refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30773/hard-disk-error) for more details.

Comment: See the following link [how to check the S.M.A.R.T. information via Disks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972978/fsck-reports-that-filesystem-still-has-errors-what-should-i-do-now/972983#972983)

Comment: The SMART test says : "Disk is OK, 15 bad sectors". And mots attributes show me "Old-Age" or "Pre-Fail" Types - On another thread, I read "Bad blocks on a modern (21st century) disk are a sign of imminent demise." => Am I wasting my time and is this disk dead ?